# join on specific criteria when duplicates exist - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the example below I'm trying to join to another table on account_number. The problem is that there are some duplicate account numbers in that table, I would like specify which one it should join on based on if the field has NULL or not.

Here is my example:

```
SELECT
 a.Account_Number
,b.Property_Address

FROM
Table1 a

left join Table2 b
on a.account_number = b.account_number

WHERE
b.property_address is not null
```

Table two currently looks like this:

Account Number  123456

Account Number  123456

Property_Address NULL

Property_Address 123 Fake Street

_

I want my query to pull this:

Account Number  123456

Property_Address 123 Fake Street

_

Currently it is pulling this:

Account Number  123456

Property_Address NULL

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your left join to an inner join and you'll probably get your desired result:

```
SELECT a.Account_Number ,b.Property_Address

FROM Table1 a

inner join Table2 b on a.account_number = b.account_number

WHERE b.property_address is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a left join, yet your where clause refers to the unpreserved table (Table2). This converts your left join into an inner join. I'll guess that this is probably not what you want. Rather you want to include those rows from Table2 where the column is not null. So move the condition from the where clause into the join. E.g.,

```
left join Table2 as b on a.account_number = b.account_number 
and b.property_address is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT account_number, property_address
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE property_address IS NOT NULL )

SELECT 
     a.Account_Number
    ,b.Property_Address
FROM CTE b 
INNER JOIN Table1 a ON b.Account_Number = a.Account_Number
```